# CSS Max-width empty area

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I try to create a responsive menu. To make it, I use max-width for the main container.

In my menu, there are a logo, the first menu, and the second menu. Logo and the first menu will be together and the last menu will be aligned to right. I am trying to make it with flexbox. You can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/c64maq7s/23/

I want the menu width to be 900pixels. However, since I use max-width for responsive design it is not 900pixels in the bigger screens or browsers. (i want a 900px menu and as the browser becomes smaller, the space between the first menu and a second menu will be smaller up until no space between them.)

How can I ensure the menu will be 900pixel totally by keeping the code as max-width?

```css
 body{
  font-family:sans-serif;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  height:100vh;
  max-width:900px;
}

nav{
  display:flex;
}

nav ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

nav ul li{
  list-style-type:none;
}

nav ul.nav{
  display:flex;
}

nav ul.nav li{
  padding:0px 10px;
}

nav ul.secondary-nav{
  display:flex;
  margin-left:50px;
}

nav ul.secondary-nav li{
  padding:0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-apple" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M11.182.008C11.148-.03 9.923.023 8.857 1.18c-1.066 1.156-.902 2.482-.878 2.516.024.034 1.52.087 2.475-1.258.955-1.345.762-2.391.728-2.43zm3.314 11.733c-.048-.096-2.325-1.234-2.113-3.422.212-2.189 1.675-2.789 1.698-2.854.023-.065-.597-.79-1.254-1.157a3.692 3.692 0 0 0-1.563-.434c-.108-.003-.483-.095-1.254.116-.508.139-1.653.589-1.968.607-.316.018-1.256-.522-2.267-.665-.647-.125-1.333.131-1.824.328-.49.196-1.422.754-2.074 2.237-.652 1.482-.311 3.83-.067 4.56.244.729.625 1.924 1.273 2.796.576.984 1.34 1.667 1.659 1.899.319.232 1.219.386 1.843.067.502-.308 1.408-.485 1.766-.472.357.013 1.061.154 1.782.539.571.197 1.111.115 1.652-.105.541-.221 1.324-1.059 2.238-2.758.347-.79.505-1.217.473-1.282z"/>
  <path d="M11.182.008C11.148-.03 9.923.023 8.857 1.18c-1.066 1.156-.902 2.482-.878 2.516.024.034 1.52.087 2.475-1.258.955-1.345.762-2.391.728-2.43zm3.314 11.733c-.048-.096-2.325-1.234-2.113-3.422.212-2.189 1.675-2.789 1.698-2.854.023-.065-.597-.79-1.254-1.157a3.692 3.692 0 0 0-1.563-.434c-.108-.003-.483-.095-1.254.116-.508.139-1.653.589-1.968.607-.316.018-1.256-.522-2.267-.665-.647-.125-1.333.131-1.824.328-.49.196-1.422.754-2.074 2.237-.652 1.482-.311 3.83-.067 4.56.244.729.625 1.924 1.273 2.796.576.984 1.34 1.667 1.659 1.899.319.232 1.219.386 1.843.067.502-.308 1.408-.485 1.766-.472.357.013 1.061.154 1.782.539.571.197 1.111.115 1.652-.105.541-.221 1.324-1.059 2.238-2.758.347-.79.505-1.217.473-1.282z"/>
</svg>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="secondary-nav">
    <li>Help</li>
    <li>My Panel</li>
    <li>info@apple.com</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I entirely understand the purpose of the `max-width: 900px;`. However, I would nest your `nav` in a div. In this example, I called it `navbar`. You can set your flex and max-width on that element. I don't know what your end goal will consist of but I would never apply `display: flex;` on the `body` element nor `max-width`. I flexed the `navbar` class I added and set up a media query instructing the browser to make `font-size: smaller;` at 600px

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul.nav {
  display: flex;
}

nav ul.nav li {
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

nav ul.secondary-nav {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

nav ul.secondary-nav li {
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 900px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar {
    font-size: smaller;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-apple" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M11.182.008C11.148-.03 9.923.023 8.857 1.18c-1.066 1.156-.902 2.482-.878 2.516.024.034 1.52.087 2.475-1.258.955-1.345.762-2.391.728-2.43zm3.314 11.733c-.048-.096-2.325-1.234-2.113-3.422.212-2.189 1.675-2.789 1.698-2.854.023-.065-.597-.79-1.254-1.157a3.692 3.692 0 0 0-1.563-.434c-.108-.003-.483-.095-1.254.116-.508.139-1.653.589-1.968.607-.316.018-1.256-.522-2.267-.665-.647-.125-1.333.131-1.824.328-.49.196-1.422.754-2.074 2.237-.652 1.482-.311 3.83-.067 4.56.244.729.625 1.924 1.273 2.796.576.984 1.34 1.667 1.659 1.899.319.232 1.219.386 1.843.067.502-.308 1.408-.485 1.766-.472.357.013 1.061.154 1.782.539.571.197 1.111.115 1.652-.105.541-.221 1.324-1.059 2.238-2.758.347-.79.505-1.217.473-1.282z"/>
  <path d="M11.182.008C11.148-.03 9.923.023 8.857 1.18c-1.066 1.156-.902 2.482-.878 2.516.024.034 1.52.087 2.475-1.258.955-1.345.762-2.391.728-2.43zm3.314 11.733c-.048-.096-2.325-1.234-2.113-3.422.212-2.189 1.675-2.789 1.698-2.854.023-.065-.597-.79-1.254-1.157a3.692 3.692 0 0 0-1.563-.434c-.108-.003-.483-.095-1.254.116-.508.139-1.653.589-1.968.607-.316.018-1.256-.522-2.267-.665-.647-.125-1.333.131-1.824.328-.49.196-1.422.754-2.074 2.237-.652 1.482-.311 3.83-.067 4.56.244.729.625 1.924 1.273 2.796.576.984 1.34 1.667 1.659 1.899.319.232 1.219.386 1.843.067.502-.308 1.408-.485 1.766-.472.357.013 1.061.154 1.782.539.571.197 1.111.115 1.652-.105.541-.221 1.324-1.059 2.238-2.758.347-.79.505-1.217.473-1.282z"/>
</svg>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="secondary-nav">
      <li>Help</li>
      <li style="white-space: nowrap;">My Panel</li>
      <li>info@apple.com</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```